# Show a button on another controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have two controller, one controller is controllerOne.swift, in this I receive notifications and I need when one notification arrive, show a button on controllerTwo.swift.

My code is:

ControllerOne.swift

```
public func websocket(token: Any){
        self.ws.open("ws://"+String(APIHOST)+":"+String(port)+"/ws?token="+String(describing: token))
        self.ws.event.message = { message in
            let res = self.convertToDictionary(text: message as! String)

            if ((res!["notification"]) != nil) {
                self.count_total_notifications_ws = self.count_total_notifications_ws! + 1
                let presentView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? SWRevealViewController

                let tabbarController = presentView?.frontViewController as? UITabBarController

                if (tabbarController?.selectedIndex != 0) {
                    tabbarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeValue = self.count_total_notifications_ws?.description
                }else{
                    //Here I need to show a showNotificationsbtn button
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ControllerTwo.swift

```
class NewDashboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

    //This is the button that I need show
    @IBOutlet weak var showNotificationsbtn: UIButton!  

    @IBAction func showNotifications(_ sender: Any) {true
        self.viewDidAppear(true)
        showNotificationsbtn.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

Someone know how to I can do?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that which button you talking about, Is it ControllerOne or ControllerTwo?

Comment: Yes, it is the showNotificationsbtn button of controllerTwo, the one that I need to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In ViewControllerOne**

```
  if ((res!["notification"]) != nil) {
                self.count_total_notifications_ws = self.count_total_notifications_ws! + 1
                let presentView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? SWRevealViewController

                let tabbarController = presentView?.frontViewController as? UITabBarController

                if (tabbarController?.selectedIndex != 0) {
                    tabbarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeValue = self.count_total_notifications_ws?.description
                }else{
                    //Here I need to show a showNotificationsbtn button
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "remoNotificationArrived"), object: nil, userInfo: nil )
                }
            }
```

**In ViewControllerTwo**

```
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(true)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showButton), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "remoNotificationArrived"), object: nil)

            }
    }

  func showButton(){
       showNotificationsbtn.isHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: You have made my day! This works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

First hide your button.
Now to unhide that button,you have multiple options.
1. Use delgate/protocol for communicating between viewcontrollers
2. You may add an observer